# ExcelDNA not working when getScreentip ribbon xml attribute is set

Tags: c#, excel, excel-dna, ribbonx

Without putting entire ribbon xml, here is my button:

```
<button id="getLatestCEVersion" keytip="N" label="Download Latest" screentip="Download latest version of this CalcEngine" imageMso="MarkForDownload" onAction="RibbonXOnActionWithTag" tag="GetCurrentCalcEngine" size="large" getEnabled="RibbonXGetEnabled" />
```

Everything works as expected.  If I simply add the `getScreentip` attribute like this:

```
<button id="getLatestCEVersion" keytip="N" label="Download Latest" screentip="Download latest version of this CalcEngine" imageMso="MarkForDownload" onAction="RibbonXOnActionWithTag" tag="GetCurrentCalcEngine" size="large" getEnabled="RibbonXGetEnabled" getScreentip="RibbonXGetScreentip" />
```

The ribbon onload event is never called (set via `<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" onLoad="RibbonXOnLoad">`) and ribbon is not set and therefore throws exception when I try to invalidate ribbon controls.

```
        public void RibbonXOnLoad( IRibbonUI ribbon )
        {
            this.ribbon = ribbon;
        }
```

I don't think my code matters for the screen tip handler because it doesn't even get into it, but here it is:

```
        public string RibbonXGetScreentip( IRibbonControl control )
        {
            switch ( control.Id )
            {
                case "getLatestCEVersion":
                    return "Download latest version of this CalcEngine";
                case "checkInCalcEngine":
                    return "Check CalcEngine into Management Site";
                case "checkOutCalcEngine":
                    return "Check CalcEngine out from Management Site";

                default: throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
            }
        }
```

Does ExcelDna support `getScreentip`?  Not a lot of info out there, but I have seen a few samples that are supposedly using it, so I think it must be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Ribbon definition becomes invalid when you add the `getScreentip` in your example because **the `screentip` and `getScreentip` attributes are mutually exclusive** (as per Microsoft's Ribbon XML specification), and they cannot be used together.

i.e. To use `getScreentip`, remove the `screentip` attribute.

Comment: There's a neat option in Excel under File -> Options -> Advanced (General) called "Show add-in user interface errors" that makes Excel pop up with these kinds of problems in the xml.

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev The tip from Govert worked as he expected FYI.